# Explanations for continue downvotes

Tags: discussion

I adding the images of last mounth because I receive any downvotes by some user who does not tell me what's wrong with my question/answer. I wonder whether there is any reason for this. Thank you.

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: voting is anonymous, since we we don't know who voted and only the person who voted can say what they didn't like then what answer do you expect to get here? In anycase it's only a few votes, look at stackoverflow people regularly get dozens of downvotes on a single question.

Comment: for what it's worth I just looked at the \sqrt question and the tikz-cd answer and can't see any reason to downvote either, but people will vote how they want, that's how the site works.

Comment: I agree with @DavidCarlisle that, if the downvotes come from a single user, only this user will be able to answer your question. And since you already asked that question often in the comments, chances are that the user prefers to be anonymous. That is, even though I do understand your frustration, I am not sure if your question will help you overcome it.

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle and marmot, I can guarantee that I do my best and thanks to you I am improving day after day. As I have always written in my comments for me has no relevance to the downvote but rather understand what is not right. Perhaps tonight or as soon as possible I will remove my question here on goal as soon as you have seen this comment. I fully accept your comments and send you my sincere greetings.