# Winter double hats for my gr(avatar) in TeX.SE and others communities

Tags: support, bug, winterbash

In these days of Winter bash, I have observed that I have often two consecutive hats :-)?

> It is normal or usual? Does this happen only to me or to other users as well?

[image]

Comment: @downvoter: Is there a clear reason for your excellent **downvoted**?

Comment: Possibly related to the previous comment: [Explanations for continue downvotes](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7774/explanations-for-continue-downvotes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These types of bug are not specific to TeX.SX, so you should report at the main https://meta.stackexchange.com, as bug reports here are much (*much*) less likely to be seen by one of the devs.  That said, it has already been reported: [Hat duplicates when info is expanded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357935/383578) and [After "run code snippet" winter hat image create duplicate image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358152/383578) (no official reply at the time of writing this).

Comment: You are always kind to me and I thank you for your response. Thank you for the clarification.